# Non magical elemental damage in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any source of elemental damage that is not magical damage in skyrim?

In other words, is there any fire/frost/shock damage that is not affected by resist magic in skyrim?

Is burning damage magical damage?

I would like to extend this question to poison as well; however, I believe most poison damage is non magical. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7):

**Poison** is not considered magical, however **Poison Damage Reduction** does exist such as the **Bosmer's Special Ability**

> Resist Disease and Poison:
>
> Your Bosmer blood gives you 50% resistance
> to poison and disease

To answer the other half of your question, no there are no non-magical sources of fire/frost/lightning damage. This means that **magical resistance will always work**, as will fire/frost/lightning resistance respectively

It's worth noting that there are traps that do one of those kinds of damage, but it's considered  magic damage (Ex: Flamethrower in dungeons). And your damage reduction will work on said traps.

Sources:

- [IGN's Race Comparison](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/skyrim-full-list-of-races-and-starting-stat-bonuses-special-abilities.206648037/)
- [UESP's trap mechanics/information](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Traps)

Comment: May I ask where you got your sources from?

Comment: http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/skyrim-full-list-of-races-and-starting-stat-bonuses-special-abilities.206648037/ This article is quite useful to compare races, and it's where I got that quote from

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Traps This article details how traps work, and that they do not ignore resistances

Comment: Do you mind putting that link in your answer proper?

Comment: Yea sure, it's done

Comment: In the traps section, I could not find a citation that all magical traps do magical damage. Though since they are called magical traps, I suppose they'd have to do magical damage, huh?

Comment: At the very first sentence under Magical Traps "all cause elemental or magical damage".

Comment: @Oak Since the question is about *whether* elemental damage is always magical damage, an indication that they do elemental *or* magical damage doesn't mean that they definitely do magic damage. They could still do non-magic elemental damage.

Comment: Weird that lava does magical damage.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Liquid rocks? sounds like magic to me!

Comment: Yeah, "elemental or magical damage" is not the same as "elemental and magical damage".

Answer (score 3):

According to the description for the [Resist Magic](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Resist_Magic_(Skyrim)) effect:

> Resist Magic is capped at 85%, **this includes all forms of elemental** and dragon breath **attacks**.

On this page, it is also noted that Resist Magic is more versatile than simple elemental resistances:

> Gaining a resistance to magic can negate a percentage of all incoming spells. It is more versatile than elemental resistance **as it covers all kinds of magical damage instead of just fire, frost, or shock individually**.

Thus, Resist Magic covers all sources of elemental damage, including damage on elemental weapons, such as the [Aegisbane](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aegisbane).

Comment: +1, that's significantly more convincing than the other answer mentioning traps, although who knows where the wiki got that information.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the Creation Kit, it appears the effect from the [Staff of Magnus](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Staff_of_Magnus) does not have a resist value listed.  I'm a bit skeptical that I'm not missing something though, since the UESP do not mention that it is special in not being affected by resistance.

Similarly, with the exception of the "Fake Lightning Bolt" effect, the [Skull of Corruption](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skull_of_Corruption) has no resistances listed for any of its damaging effects.

It looks like some elemental traps have a resistance listed and some don't.  Someone more familiar with the CK than I might be able to tell you where some examples are actually located, the best I can tell is what cell they are located in (e.g. Saarthal02).